# How to convert Word 2007 document to PDF using Apache FOP

Tags: ms-word, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am currently using Apache FOP and have a stylesheet (possibly from RenderX) that converts Word 2003 XML documents (Saved as XML option) to PDF.  However, this does not work for Word 2007 XML documents.

I am looking for options and/or suggestions on how to accomplish one of the following tasks -

Get a stylesheet that will transform Word 2007 XML file to:

1. Word 2003 XML or
2. PDF using FOP (using a stylesheet to create xsl-fo)

I am also open to any other options you might have.  If possible I would like to do this with little to no cost.  However, I am limited to using Java so a C# type option is not possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j), an open source Java library (ASL v2) which uses FOP to create PDFs from docx files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will look into it.  However, I was hoping for a Stylesheet type solution since it fits in the existing framework.  Going the docx4j will require multiple changes.

Comment: docx4j does use XSLT to create XSL-FO, albeit with Java extension functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any style sheets that do this transformation.  It would be reasonably sophisticated.  If you end up having to engineer another way of doing it, you might want to look at [JODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) (straight conversion - might be your best bet), the OpenOffice UNO API (very manual), [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) (both can produce documents in various formats).  All can produce PDFs from a Java environment.  I think they all have free versions.

Hope that helps.